# setInterval and css() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, setinterval

I have a strange problem with `setInterval()` and `css()`.

Everytime, but in this case, the first hit with the div `#letterspacing` and the div `#bowl` should change the background image...

I have the following code:

```
setInterval(function() {    
    if(collision($('#letterspacing'), $('#bowl'))){
        $('#bowl').css('background-image', 'url(../Images/bowl_1.png)');
        $('#letterspacing').fadeOut(2000);
        $('.frage1').fadeOut(1000);
        $('.frage2').fadeIn(2000);
    }
}, 400);
```

But my image does not change. When I add the function over the `setInterval()` it works.

Comment: I don't understand what this means: *"When i add the function over the setIntervall() it works"* Does this mean that if you remove the function from the `setInterval`, and invoke it manually, it works?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the DOM is not loaded at the time you change the css. make sure you call it when DOM is loaded. in `window.onload` for example.

Comment: "When i add the function over the setIntervall() it works" i mean with that,  when the css() function is not within the setInterfall()-Function, it works. Exactly it is the first line in my Javascript document.